# Highcharts download menu disabled when removing title

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Whenever I set the title of the chart to null, I can't click on the download menu of my chart anymore.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/JVNjs/954/

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo:'container',
        borderWidth:1,
        plotBorderWidth:1
    },
    title:{
        text:null
    },
    subTitle:{
        text:null
    },
    credits:{enabled:false},
    legend:{
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            shadow:false,
            borderWidth:0,
        }
    },
    xAxis:{
        lineColor:'#999',
        lineWidth:1,
        tickColor:'#666',
        tickLength:3,
        title:{
            text:'X Axis Title'
        }
    },
    yAxis:{
        lineColor:'#999',
        lineWidth:1,
        tickColor:'#666',
        tickWidth:1,
        tickLength:3,
        gridLineColor:'#ddd',
        title:{
            text:'Y Axis Title',
            rotation:0,
            margin:50,
        }
    },    
    series: [{
        data: [7,12,16,32,60]
    }]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: In your link my only problem is with the JSFiddle overlay blocking the button. If I add a few `<br />` to get the chart away from the "Result" overlay I can click the button perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused only by jsfiddle `text overlap`. If you run full showcase, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/JVNjs/954/show/ then all works properly.